# How to prove that a function on a quotient set $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is well defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, multiplicative-function, quotient-set

I am asked to prove that a function under a quotient set is well-defined. I know that for a function to be well-defined, two mappings or images found in the co-domain/range can't be mapped from the same argument in the domain. But I don't know how to prove it under this multiplicative group:
$f: \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, $[a] \mapsto [a^2]$.
Thank you

Comment: More simply put, any two representatives from the same class should map to the same class. So given $m$, and $m+kn$ for any $m,k\in\mathbb Z$, can you show that $[m^2]=[(m+kn)^2]$? That would finish the problem.

Comment: You need to take $[a] = [b]$ and show that $[a^2] = [b^2]$

Comment: Perhaps try this rephrasing of the question: 

Is it possible that we might find $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a^2 = b^2$ but $a \neq b$?  Why or why not?

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

If you have $[a]=[b]$ then you need to prove that $[a^2]=[b^2]$ too.

Remember that $[a]=[b]$ implies that $a-b$ is a multiple of the modulus $n$, that is, $a-b=kn$ for some integer $k$.